# Razor Pages - How to add model data to hardcoded select options if the value is matching

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a hardcoded select options on my Razor page.

Here is the select portion:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5 input-group">
                        <select class="custom-select" id="validationCustom04" required>
                            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
                            <option value="000000001585">2100 ZA</option>
                            <option value="000000001570">10 TL'lik Steam Bakiyesi</option>
                            <option value="000000001696">4300 ZA</option>
                            <option value="000000001572">400 Riot Points</option>
                            <option value="000000001573">840 Riot Points</option>
                            <option value="000000001574">Gameforge 6 TRY E-Pin</option>
                            <option value="000000001575">50 Hükümdarlık</option>
                            <option value="000000001582">10 TL Razer Gold Pin</option>
                            <option value="000000001583">25 TL Razer Gold Pin</option>
                            <option value="000000001705">20 TL'lik Steam Bakiyesi</option>
                            <option value="000000001706">9000 ZA</option>
                            <option value="0187022">10 TL Razer Gold Pin</option>
                            <option value="0186479">10 TL Steam Cüzdan Kodu</option>

                        </select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please select a game.
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

Here is the sample model I am using:

```
public class GameBanksDto
    {
        [DisplayName("Product Code")] public string ProductCode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")] public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Unit Price")] public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Stock Quantity")] public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the list I am passing to the Razor page:

```
var gamestock = await _context.GameBanks
                .Where(m => m.used == 0)
                .Where(n => n.status == 0)
                .Where(p => p.status == 2)
                .GroupBy(g => new
                {
                    g.ProductCode,
                  
                })
                .Select(gcs => new GameBanksDTO
                {
                    ProductCode = gcs.Key.ProductCode,
                    Quantity = gcs.Count(g => g.Quantity)
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Is it possible to add Quantity to the matching hard coded values on the select options? (I assume 000000001585 is matching the model product code.)

```
<option value="000000001585">2100 ZA *Stock Quantity:100*</option>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When did you want to add corresponding Quantity to select option?The application run or when you select the item?And why did you do such thing?I think no matter it should do or not,it is a complex thing and make performance lower.

Comment: Put your "hard coded" values in a List or Dictionary or something, then output them in the Razor page using a @foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your hard coded value by using jQuery like below:

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    $("#validationCustom04 > option").each(function () {
        var count = '@Model.GameBanksDto.Count';
        if (count != '') {
            var item = true;
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.GameBanksDto.Count; i++) {
                    @: item = `@Model.GameBanksDto[i].ProductCode`;
                    @:if (item == this.value)
                    @: {
                         @: var value = this.text;
                         @: $(this).text(value +" Stock Quantity: "+ '@Model.GameBanksDto[i].Quantity')
                    @:}
            }
        }
    });

})
</script>
```

Backend code:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<GameBanksDto> GameBanksDto { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
       //for easy testing I hard coded the data
        GameBanksDto = new List<GameBanksDto>()
        {
            new GameBanksDto(){ProductCode="000000001585",Quantity=12},
            new GameBanksDto(){ProductCode="000000001570",Quantity=34},
            new GameBanksDto(){ProductCode="000000001696",Quantity=32},
            new GameBanksDto(){ProductCode="000000001572",Quantity=33}
        };

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]